# Index and Title Page font in book class

Tags: titles, sectsty

I am using the `book` class. In the preamble I have:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
```

to change the font of chapters and sections. I would also like the title page where it shows the title, author, and date to be that font also. How what do I need to add to do this?

Also, I was looking the documentation for the `book` class and it seems to have the capability to make an index. I tried

```
\begin{theindex}
\item{Number, Prime}
\end{theindex}
```

but I am not sure how the page numbering for the index works. Do I have to manually put it in or is it like other packages where I can denote it next to the word as it appears in my boo?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For the first point, `\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{titlepage}{\sffamily}` should do the trick. For the index, I do not quite understand: do you want to make an index by hand?

Comment: Those ae two very different question, i suggest to divide them into separate questions.

Comment: For the titlepage, you can do what Bernard already wrote. You can also have a look at [Ho to customize my titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280) or [Title Creation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation) if you need something non-standard.

Comment: You have two compeltely different questions put in one. That would be fine for a discussion forum, but here, it isn't good at all. The question (and answer) will be confusing for other users searching for a solution. If i wouldn't just having my coffee, i would vote to close the question as too broad. Why? It is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard automatic index with in LaTeX need this minimal structure:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex 
\begin{document}
Hello world\index{World}  
\printindex{}
\end{document}
```

Note that `pdflatex` will not make the index, but a auxiliary file `.idx` that then must be processed by `makeindex`, that not surprisingly, make the index with, but in another auxiliary file with `.ind` extension with content like `\indexentry{Word}{3}`. Then run `pdflatex` again at least two times to include that entries in the PDF.

Search in https://www.ctan.org/topic/index for several alternatives to `makeidx` packages.

For the font of  title, author, and date, the simplest is:

1) Switch to `scrbook` class. The default for title and sections is nearly of what you want, except for author and date, but this can be changed with `\setkomafont` without messing up their arguments:.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setkomafont{author}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{date}{\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\title{The title}
\author{You}
\date{today}
\maketitle
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

2) include the desired format in the argument, i.e., `\title{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries ...}`  and so on. People (me too) hate this because is against principle of the separation of formats and contents in LaTeX, but any other solution add enough code in the preamble to see this not too bad. See however `titling` and `titlepages` packages if you want  custom title pages.

Comment: Another question that holds to questions, each of which probably a duplicate, and an answer. Tagging around here is almost useless.

Comment: I wonder what another user is thinking when searching for a solution on this site. But this probably is one for meta.